# Path of clicked file to be passed in batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, windows-7, cmd, environment-variables

I've a question to ask related to windows batch scripting. I've a batch file lets say **xyz.bat** which runs a **Java rich client application**. This application takes a H2 database file as input. Now what I'm trying to do is that on double clicking to a H2 database file, the above batch file gets triggered and launches the application and then that database file we clicked on, gets opened in the application. To do this, I've configured the database files having a special extension **(*.ult)** to be opened with **xyz.bat**. Now this batch file needs the path of database file we clicked on to pass to the application so that the applications opens this database file on startup. Hence I need some sort of environment or system variable which captures the path of last clicked file so that I can use that variable in my **xyz.bat** and that way the path is redirected to Java application on startup. Any sort of help or suggestion is appreciated. I'm counting on you. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is the databese file located in the same folder as the .bat file?

Comment: No, it can be anywhere ...

Comment: The name and the location of database file is not fix .. it could be anything.

Answer (score 3):

Handler configuration (can be run from command line) to associate `.ult` files with a batch file

```
assoc .ult=ULTfile
ftype ULTfile="C:\Some\Where\ULTHandler.cmd" "%1"
```

The batch file (`ULTHandler.cmd`)

```
@echo off
    File is "%~1"
    pause
```

The file reference is retrieved via `%1`, that is, the first parameter to the batch file. `%~1` is the same first parameter without quotes (if present)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the solution I was looking for. Great help.

Comment: You don't need to pass "%1" manually. %1 in the batch file will always give you the pass wo the original file.

Comment: @MichaelS, it is necessary to include the "%1" in the ftype command. Without it the reference to the double clicked file is not passed to the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%CD%`! Say your database file is located in `C:\Database\dbfile.dbf`
You open all .dbf files with a batch file located in `C:\YourBat\batfile.bat`
Now if you doubleclick on `dbfile.dbf` and use `%CD%` inside your `.bat`, you will get the path `C:\Database\`
So `%CD%` is the answer :D

EDIT:
Ok, thats ever better :D `%1` will give you the path to the original file!

Comment: Thank you so much. this is really helpful. Just another thing, this way I can get the directory but how do I pass the name of file I clicked on. Its because C:\Database\ may have many database files with different names all compatible to be opened with Java application. Thanx.

Comment: Ok, thats ever better :D %1 will give you the path to the original file!